# Datepicker not working in ionic ios

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using cordoca datepicker plugin , it works fine in android but in ios it have some issues .

when i am clicking date picker a keyboard overlaps datepicker then it stuck .

`<label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon-clock"></i>
    <input type="date" id="date-format" ng-click="loadDate()"  placeholder="Select date & time (dd/mm/yyyy H:m:a)" ng-model="meetingData.enddate">
  </label>`

Answer (score 4):

Try with this

#### Add readonly for this input tag

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <i class="icon-clock"></i>
  <input type="date" id="date-format" ng-click="loadDate()" placeholder="Select date & time (dd/mm/yyyy H:m:a)" ng-model="meetingData.enddate" readonly > </label>
```

Comment: Not working:
 <label class="item item-input form-input-number">
                    <input type="date"  placeholder="Date of birth"
                           ng-model="$parent.age"
                           ng-click="startDatePicker()" readonly required>
                </label>